# how to convert get_comment_date() wordpress function to return persian date

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, persian-calendar

In wordpress I use code below to get today persian's date.

```php
function getDateIntl(?\DateTime $date = null, ?string $locale = null, ?DateTimeZone $timezone = null, $dateFormat)
{
    $date = $date ?? new \DateTime();
    $locale = $locale ?? \Locale::getDefault();
    $formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(
        $locale,
        IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        $timezone,
        IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL,
        $dateFormat
    );
    return $formatter->format($date);
}
echo getDateIntl(new DateTime(), "fa@calendar=persian", new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Tehran'), 'eeee، dd MMMM');
```

Now I'm in single blog posts and want to use this function to convert comments date to perisan
defualt function of comment date is: get_comment_date()

defualt funtion of wordpress returns string that I can not replace it with "new DateTime()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress has a special [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_comment_date/) in which you can do any manipulation with the date when the function `get_comment_date()` will be used:

```php
add_filter( 'get_comment_date', 'my_get_comment_date_filter', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Function for `get_comment_date` filter-hook.
 * 
 * @param string|int $date    Formatted date string or Unix timestamp.
 * @param string     $format  PHP date format.
 * @param WP_Comment $comment The comment object.
 *
 * @return string|int
 */
function my_get_comment_date_filter( $date, $format, $comment ){

    // filter...
    return $date;
}
```